# Writing geopackage attribute data in Python using Fiona module

Tags: python, python-3.x, gis, fiona, geopackage

I have very little experience in fiona module (started today!)
I have a geopackage called building.gpkg that has a field called 'id' which is NULL at the time of production.

I am trying to write a python script using fiona module to populate its ID according to IDs available in another table stored in SQL Server.

While I have successfully imported and read bldg.gpkg via fiona, I am struggling to write the data into the id column:

Here is the sample code:

```
import fiona
bldg_gpkg = 'building.gpkg'

with fiona.open(bldg_gpkg, 'w') as c:
    for i in range(max_id, len(list(c))+max_id):
        c.next()['properties']['id'] = i
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python3\lib\site-packages\fiona\env.py", line 407, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python3\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py", line 265, in open
    c = Collection(path, mode, crs=crs, driver=driver, schema=this_schema,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python3\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py", line 126, in __init__
    raise DriverError("no driver")
fiona.errors.DriverError: no driver
```

I looked in collection.py and in drvsupport.py in fiona module and GPKG drived is installed and supported
Is there something I am missing? or is the writing method wrong?

I am running Python 3.8.1 on Windows 10.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

New to GIS as well, but I think you need to use a fiona driver that has write capabilities.

I believe that fiona uses the OpenFileGDB driver by default, which only has read capabilities.

Run `fiona.supported_drivers` to see what drivers are supported in your installation, and what read or write capabilities they have.

Try this:

```
with fiona.open(bldg_gpkg, 'w',
    driver='GPKG',
    schema=schema,
    crs=crs) as c:
```

You'll need to supply the schema of your data, as well as the crs, as python dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you, with the driver, schema and crs attributes, I resolved the no driver error. I am now having a completely different error where I am not allowed to assign a value with the statement:

```
c.next()['properties']['id'] = i
```
It appears that next() works only for files that are set in read mode